# Hello! I have problems with my ubuntu18.04(amd64) desktop virtualization machines

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I have problems with my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop virtualization machines on my windows 10 on Oracle Virtual Box version 5.2.22. They lag. I have the following parameters set:

> Ram: 4096 MB
>
> 1 CPU, limit of execution 100%
>
> In acceleration I have marked the checkbox Vt-x/AMD-v
>
> Video memory 128 MB
>
> VBOX additions installed

At the beginning the machine goes well but after 2 or 3 min of opening the programs or chrome or whatever it starts to go very slow.
I've read that virtualization needs to be enabled from setup. I don't have that option on my setup but I've also read that if I go to the Task Manager and then to Performance and click on CPU on the right-bottom corner I can see virtualization is enabled.

Comment: @ThomasWard As i understand it, it is Ubuntu VMs on a Win10 host...

Comment: Probably still low resources.  Standard Ubuntu needs more than 1CPU, Lubuntu works better with 1CPU than standard Ubuntu does (GNOME is greedy)

Answer (score 0):

You can check if you have the virtualization enabled in the BIOS by trying to temporarily give more than one CPU to a VM (IIRC this is disabled if you have no hardware support or virtualization).

Other than that, when the guest system performance monitor to see what is limiting it (RAM/Swapping, CPU...) and the hosts performance monitor for same.

Otherwise, give more indication about the host hardware, and the VM settings (video support: 2D? 3D?).

Comment: Thank you for answering. I have 3D acceleration. And i can add more than 1 CPU to de VM but I dont understand this part: Other than that, when the guest system performance monitor to see what is limiting it (RAM/Swapping, CPU...) and the hosts performance monitor for same.

Comment: Try to use only 2D acceleration, virtualized 3D is rarely good. Otherwise, the machine lags because it lacks some resource, and the perf monitor may tell you which resource is maxxed out on the VM (and perhaps also on the host).

Comment: Im not able to use 2D acceleration on ubunuts just on windows

Answer (score 0):

I'm no pro, but maybe give virt-manager a try instead of virtualbox. The gui is far simpler, but also can all be done direct from the command line. It seems to put less of a strain on my system anyways.